# The positional $ operator in MongoDB does not seem to update multiple documents

Tags: mongodb-query, positional-operator

The following is a modified example from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#examples

```
db.students.insert([
   { "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 80, 80 ] },
   { "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 90, 92 ] },
   { "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
])

db.students.updateOne(
   { _id: 1, grades: 80 },
   { $set: { "grades.$" : 82 } }
   { multi: true }
)'
```

I expect `{multi: true}` to update multiple documents that match the selector criteria.

As a matter of fact, the following doesn't seem to work either:

```
db.students.insert([
       { "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 82, 82 ] },
       { "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 90, 92 ] },
       { "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 80, 100, 90 ] }
    ])

    db.students.updateOne(
       { _id: 1, grades: 80 },
       { $set: { "grades.$" : 82 } }
       { multi: true }
    )'
```

I expect the third document to be updated to `{"_id" : 3, "grades" : [82, 100, 90]}`

Comment: `{multi: true}` will update multiple documents but `_id` is unique...if you query on a specific `_id` value you will update at most 1 document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query clause is `{ _id: 1, grades: 80 }` but `id:1` has `grades : [ 85, 82, 82 ]`.  The third document will not be updated because it has `_id:3` which does not match your query clause.

Pro tip: before running `update` execute a `find` to get a preview of what may be updated*.

```
 db.students.find({ _id: 1, grades: 80 })
```

*`find` will return all matches while `updateOne` will update at most 1 document but at least you'll know your query clause works.

Comment: Thanks Paul! That makes sense.  I should've understood the example more before tinkering with `{multi: true}`.

Comment: Tinkering is often the best way to understand how example code works.  I've learned a lot from breaking example code!